# How to get an URL parameter with value `/` (slash) - Magento

Tags: php, magento, encryption, parameters

How to get an URL parameter with value `/` because I have a value

```
$encrypted = "Dwe/OAISUD";

www.test.com/test/test/index/encrypted/Dwe/OAISUD
```

then I want to get it with controller `getParam('encrypted');`

but in controller I get value

```
$encrypted = "Dwe";
```

How to fix that? On Magento way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$encrypted = urlencode("Dwe/OAISUD");
```

Comment: nice answer! then to decode it again using, urldecode("Dwe%2FOAISUD");

Comment: Be careful, one site has returned 404 because of `%2F` in the query string. Changing that to `/` loaded the page, but of course returned the wrong value to the controller